# Intersection of integer lists - unable to return the resultant list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have written a code for the intersection of two linkedLists. I tried it on
the Leetcode site and my code ran without any errors. I was trying out with a custom driver functions in main, and I don't receive the desired output.

Not sure where I'm going wrong. Can anyone pointout what I'm missing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct ListNode {

int val;
ListNode *next;
ListNode(int x): val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

class Solution {
public:
    ListNode *getIntersection(ListNode *A, ListNode *B) {
        ListNode *p1 = A;
        ListNode *p2 = B;


        if(p1==NULL || p2==NULL)
            return NULL;

        while(p1!=NULL && p2!=NULL && p1!=p2) {
            p1=p1->next;
            p2=p2->next;

            if(p1==p2)
                return p1;

            if(p1==NULL) p1=B;
            if(p2==NULL) p2=A;    
        }

        return p1;
    }

    void print(ListNode *p) {
        while(p!=NULL) {
            cout<< p->val << " " ;
            p=p->next;  
        }

        cout<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Solution s;
    ListNode *p1 = new ListNode(5);
    p1->next = new ListNode(11);

    s.print(p1);
    //similar for p2

    ListNode *p2 = new ListNode(6);
    p2->next = new ListNode(11);
    s.print(p2);

    s.getIntersection(p1,p2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When writing code like this it really helps to have some solid unit tests you can run to verify it's working correctly. Do you have any of those?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that in the while loop you're comparing `pointer-to-ListNode` and not the value(s) contained in the `ListNode`:

```
while(p1!=NULL && p2!=NULL && **p1!=p2**) {
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
                               here
    p1=p1->next;
    p2=p2->next;

    **if(p1==p2)**
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     and here
        return p1;
```

You should be doing:

```
while(p1!=NULL && p2!=NULL && p1->val!=p2->val) {
   ....
```

And then there is the problem that what you're computing might not be 'the intersection', but that's a different problem.